# Connection timed out when invoking AWS Rest API

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-ecs

I have a Spring Boot app that is deployed in AWS ECS and when I call an API endpoint that is hosted in another AWS account I get the following error:

```
connection timed out: xxxxx.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/xx.xx.xxx.xxx:443
```

When I run the app on my local machine there is no problem.

Is there anything I need to configure?

Comment: Which [network mode](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-configure-network.html) did you configure? If awsvpc then your network needs a NAT gateway.

Comment: `vpcSubnets: vpc.selectSubnets({
        subnetType: SubnetType.PRIVATE_WITH_EGRESS
      }),`
This should allow connections to the internet. I also allowed all outgoing traffic in the security group

Comment: That CDK subnet option also requires NAT gateway (unless your API endpoint is private, which it does not appear to be) so I presume you have NAT.

Comment: I just tried to send a request to another API and that's also working without a problem. 
My guess it has something to do with vpc/gateway/network between ecs and the API endpoint. But I don't understand that it's working from my local machine

Comment: Do you know anything about the [invocation policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-resource-policies.html) of the target API endpoint? How do clients authenticate to the API?

Comment: Requests are signed using the V4 signature